# Como realizar subconsulta com preenchimento automático

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, jquery-ui

Código que realizada a consulta:

```
$parametro = (isset($_GET['parametro'])) ? $_GET['parametro'] : '';

if($acao == 'consulta'):
$sql = "SELECT codigo,preco FROM produtos ";
$sql .= "WHERE descricao LIKE ? LIMIT 1";

try{
    $query_select = $conecta->prepare($sql);        
    $query_select->bindValue(1, '%'.$parametro);
    $query_select->execute();
    $dados = $query_select->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
}catch (PDOexception $error_select){
    echo 'Erro ao selecionar: '.$error_select->getMessage();
}

$json = json_encode($dados);
echo $json;
endif;
```

Carregar os dados da consulta nos campos "Código" e "Preço":

```
function carregarDados(){
    var busca = $('#busca').val();
    if(busca != "" && busca.length >= 2){
        $.ajax({
            url: "consulta.php",
            dataType: "json",   
            data: {
                acao: 'consulta',
                parametro: $('#busca').val()
            },
            success: function( data ) {
               $('#codigo').val(data[0].codigo);
               $('#preco').val(data[0].preco);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

e função para disparar o autocomplete

```
$( "#busca" ).autocomplete({
    minLength: 2,
    source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "consulta.php",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                acao: 'autocomplete',
                parametro: $('#busca').val()
            },
            success: function(data) {
               response(data);
            }
        });
    },
    focus: function( event, ui ) {
        $("#busca").val( ui.item.descricao );
        carregarDados();
        return false;
    },
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        $("#busca").val( ui.item.descricao );
        return false;
    }
})

.autocomplete( "instance" )._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
    return $( "<li>" ).append( "<strong>Código: </strong>" + item.codigo
    + "&nbsp; | &nbsp; <strong>Descrição: </strong>" + item.descricao
    + "<br>" ).appendTo(ul);
};
```

A consulta é realizada com base na descrição do campo de busca e o retorno é exibido nos campos "Código" e "Preço", contudo quando existem dois produtos com a mesma descrição e códigos diferentes os campos mencionados não são atualizados.

Ilustração:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código, explicação e execução encontrada nos *links*:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PPROnjv1fhI

http://www.devwilliam.com.br/php/autocomplete-com-jquery-ui-php-mysql

Comment: Cara, sugiro você usar o [twitter typeahead](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/#remote).

Comment: Quais erros você obteve ao tentar?